# Need explanation of 1-line Java code about inversion in array where change values of elements

Tags: java

Can somebody explain me how this code works? I beginner in Java, but want to understand this 3 lines of code)))
   Thanks...

```
public class Kata {   
    public static int[] invert(int[] array) {
        return java.util.Arrays.stream(array).map(i -> -i).toArray();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: What part of it, specifically, do you not understand?

Comment: when *new to java* you might start with the **tutorial**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Well this is pretty straight forward, it augments an array of integers into stream and map each of the elements in the stream into inverted value, e.g. multiplying by -1 and converts it back into array. In fact this similar to writing:

```
public static int[] invert(int[] array) {
    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    for (i = 0; i< array.length; ++i) {
       result[i] = -1 * array[i];
    }
    return result;  
}
```

You probably would like to take a look on following docs:

1. [JavaDoc for streaming package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)
2. [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)
3. [Understanding Java 8 Streams API](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-java-8-streams-1)

Answer (score 0):

- `public static int[] invert(int[] array) {}` is the definition of the function, it taes as parameters an array of int called 'array', and will return a array of inf (`int[]`) :
- `Arrays.stream(array)` will takes the array and convert it to a stream
- `.map(i -> -i)` will replace all value by their opposite (5 becomes -5, and -10 becomes 10)
- `.toArray()` converts the actuel stream to an array
- `return Ar......rray();` will return the new array as result

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: @RomanBanytskyy remember to accept one answer if one satitisfies you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a java library utility function you can set breakpoints and debug line by line that's the best way to learn what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will convert all the integers in the array to its negative value.

Print the following line in your code and see it yourself

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(invert(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6})));
```